# Condition for MAX(Booking) within a specific period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is looping between core working hours(7:30-16:30). 
This query returns the most recent bookings per group till date but I can't seem to figure out the condition to make sure the most recent returned was that recorded as of the loop time,

**i.e at 07:30 today, the most recent bookings from groups F01-F03 were ... regardless of the date the booking was recorded**.

My query looks like this at the moment:

```
DECLARE @ALLBOOKINGS TABLE (BOOKING_GRP NVARCHAR(3), BOOKING_DATE DATETIME)
DECLARE @MAX_BACKDATE DATE = dateadd(DAY,datediff(DAY,0,getdate())-5,0), 
@CURRENT_TIME TIME(0) = GETDATE(),
@START_TIME TIME(0) = '07:30:00';

BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @ALLBOOKINGS
        SELECT BOOKING_GRP, BOOKING_DATE
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE BOOKING_DATE >= @MAX_BACKDATE  
END

WHILE (@START_TIME <= @CURRENT_TIME)
    BEGIN   
    SELECT * 
      FROM @ALLBOOKINGS AS T1
    WHERE BOOKING_DATE = (SELECT MAX(BOOKING_DATE) FROM @ALLBOOKINGS WHERE BOOKING_GRP = T1.BOOKING_GRP)
    --AND
    --cast(BOOKING_DATE as time(0)) > @START_TIME AND cast(BOOKING_DATE as time(0)) < @CURRENT_TIME <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this does not work, only returns max till now

    SET @START_TIME = DATEADD(MINUTE,10,@START_TIME) END
```

Table:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|   BOOKING_GRP     |        BOOKING_DATE     |        @START_TIME      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|      F01          | 2018-12-10 11:48:50.363 |      07:30:00           |
|      F02          | 2018-12-10 11:22:06.367 |      07:30:00           |
|      F03          | 2018-12-10 11:21:14.240 |      07:30:00           |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
FAKE DATA - CURRENT RESULT

+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|   BOOKING_GRP     |        BOOKING_DATE     |       @START_TIME       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|      F01          | 2018-12-07 10:34:50.363 |      07:30:00           |
|      F02          | 2018-12-10 12:32:06.367 |      07:30:00           |       
|      F03          | 2018-12-06 11:37:14.240 |      07:30:00           |     
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

EXPECTED RESULT - WITHIN THE LAST 5 DAYS, THE MOST RECENT BOOKINGS MADE PER GROUP AS OF 07:30 TODAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `DATE` to the while condition

```html
DECLARE @STARTTIME dateTIME = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) + '07:30',  
@CURRENTTIME DATETIME= GETDATE()

WHILE (@START_TIME <= @CURRENT_TIME)
    BEGIN   
    SELECT * 
      FROM @ALLBOOKINGS AS T1
    WHERE BOOKING_DATE = (SELECT MAX(BOOKING_DATE) FROM @ALLBOOKINGS WHERE BOOKING_GRP = T1.BOOKING_GRP
    AND DATE_BOOKED < @STARTTIME
    )

    SET @START_TIME = DATEADD(MINUTE,10,@START_TIME) END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question, but you could give the following query a shot:

```
SELECT Booking_Group, MAX (Booking_Date) AS MaxDate
FROM SomeTable AS ST
WHERE Booking_Date BETWEEN DATEADD (MINUTE, 30, DATEADD (HH, 7, CAST (CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) ) AND GETDATE() 
GROUP BY Booking_Group
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to loop.

```
declare @start datetime = '20180101'
   ,@end datetime = getdate()

select BOOKING_GRP,max(BOOKING_DATE) as LATEST_BOOKING_DATE
from Table1
where BOOKING_DATE between @start and @end
group by BOOKING_GRP
```

Comment: The data is used to generate a graph which measures efficiency over time (ie 7:30 vs aggr. Sum, 7:40 vs aggr. Sum...) , an extra column is queried which is production time and each time slot is aggregated to calculate this efficiency.